# Additional fields in Drupal Commerce Kickstart2

Tags: drupal-7

I Would like to have a register form like that one
http://www.blackfire.eu/account.php?act=register

so I thought I go with this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSJYDjhkZJ0
but he doesn't show how to add fields or how to change some. So is some able to help me?

Answer (score -1):

You can add customer specific fields by adding fields to the Billing or Shipping Customer profiles.

Via the Admin menu:
Store -> Customer profiles -> Profile Types -> Billing/Shipping Information -> Manage Fields.

URL: yoursite.com/admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types/billing/fields

If you need to customise the checkout form further, there are a number of ways, including the following:

1) Use an existing Commerce module that provides extra fields or checkout "panes".

[Commerce Agree Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_agree_terms) - Adds a Terms and Conditions checkbox

[Commerce Extra Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_panes) - Lets you load nodes within the checkout form

2) Create a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/getting-started) and add your own checkout pane. In this pane you can add any required fields. This tutorial provides further details on how this is implemented. http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/custom-commerce-checkout-panes

3) Use the standard Drupal [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) to modify the existing checkout form. There is an example here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107310/how-to-alter-commerce-checkout-form-in-a-custom-module